# Rails remote: true only if requested through ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got my app working as I want it without AJAX.

I'm adding AJAX now to an item listing page with an 'add item' button.

Normally, clicking 'add item' it'd just go to the new item page, but with ajax it injects the new item form onto the page. On submit it updates the listing. This is all working fine, too.

However, if I visit the new item page directly, upon submitting the form it still fires the javascript. I want avoid any AJAX form submission if I'm on the form page itself.

Is it possible to only add `remote => true` to my form tag if the page has been requested through AJAX?

(...or suggest a better way to do this)

Answer (score 5):

`request.xml_http_request?` will tell you if you are serving an ajax request:

```
<% if request.xml_http_request? %>
....
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `remote => request.xml_http_request?` in my form tag. Perfect.